# right database/approach to do keyphrase queries with many possible "keys words" matching each record

Tags: database-design, associations, keyword

my rails 3 application is hosted at Heroku using postgres for the ordinary database stuff like keeping track of messages and users. 100% of my experience is with normal relational dbases and SQL.

however now I'm adding a single new method "lookup_product_by_keyword" that accesses a dataset unrelated to the rest of the app and therefore could be implemented in another framework or database. And I'm wondering if MongoDB or some other type of database might be the way to implement this one capability.

Our goal is to find one of 5000 product type ("screwdriver" "bottle opener" etc etc) that best matches a list of perhaps 50,0000 keywords and phrases. For example, there might be 10-20 words or phrases that would match and return "screwdriver" ("philips screwdriver" "flathead screwdriver" etc).

I suspect there is some type of clever design, perhaps built around a specialized database very different form MySQL, Postgres, etc. that is optimized for thsi sort of "assocative" rather than relational information structure.

Any pointers would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a database that could handle text indexing efficiently? I am not sure how a no-sql database could help you with this problem. Oracle introduced [oracle text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/text.920/a96517/cdefault.htm) from oracle 9. (I think) and I have used it to problem similar to yours and it performs admirably.

If you are looking at database vendor agnostic solution then I suggest you check our [hibernate search.](http://hibernate.org/subprojects/search) It uses the powerful lucene indexing underneath and provides a very workable abstraction layer.

Comment: no, not looking for a dbase that does better at indexing... looking for a dbase and/or structure that handles looking up according to keywords associated with an record...

Comment: the 'obvious' approach for garden variety relational dbase is is two tables: Keywords (with fields "a_keyword" and foriegn key "product_id") and Products (with fields "id", "product_name", etc) so if we find a keyword in Keywords we then have the product_id so lookup the Product. Trivially simple for exact matches. But occureed to me that there might be some different databases and or structures that handle 'fuzzy' associations nicely.

Comment: May be I do not understand your problem clearly, but I believe my solution will still work. May be the difference is, you are looking  at a new way to design the solution and I am just suggesting a implementation. Lets say that we use Hibernate Search, I can run a query on the keyword column for a "text Occurence". Since it uses lucene underneath, the search result will be fast. Then we can use Hibernate to map the search result to the actual project entity. (hibernate takes care of mapping lucene index with the primary key column of the table. So lucene search results is mapped to the entity)

Comment: http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.com/2009/02/hibernate-search-example.html an working example. Wildcard, fuzzy, proximity searching, term indexing and weighing are what lucene offers to you out of the box.